# Linq to Nhibernate Error

Tags: .net, linq, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

i am trying to implement a search method. which try to check if a string consist any element from the specified list of strings .

```
 customers = GetSession().Linq<customer>();
 if (!searchFilter.Expertises.IsEmpty())
 {
     customers = customers.Where(x => searchFilter.Expertises.Any(s => x.Spec.Expertise.Contains(s)));
 }
 return customers.ToList();
```

But this Throws an error, seems linq to nhibernate does not support "Any"

please help me implementing this

Answer (score 0):

You are right that it does not support any. I would look to rewrite this using something like PredicateBuilder :

http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

Hope this helps.